# Como utilizar múltiplas condições dentro de um if

Tags: javascript, jquery, if

Já tentei de várias maneiras, agrupando com `()` de todas as formas que imaginei, criando uma variável e chamando ela na condição etc, mas consigo encontrar onde estou errando.

```
$(function() {
    $('#id1').change(function(){
       if (($(this).val() == '3' || '4') && ('id2' == '5')) {
       $('#div1').fadeIn('slow');
       $('#div2').hide();
        }
       else if ($(this).val() == '6' || '7') {
           $('#div1').hide()
       }
        else {
           $('#div2').hide();
           $('#div1').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Já tentei assim também:

```
var tip = document.getElementById("#id2").val;
       if (($(this).val() == '3' || '4') && (tip == '5'))
```

E agrupando diferente:

```
if ($(this).val() == '3' || '4' && 'id2' == '5')
```

Ou

```
if (($(this).val() == '3' || '4') && 'id2' == '5')
```

Segue um <kbd>https://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/6e7yo7y2/2/</kbd> com o exemplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os operadores lógicos avaliam os booleanos retornados nos predicados, eles devem devem ser usados entre duas expressões (as quais resultam um booleano), ou booleanos propriamente ditos (true ou false)

Você está errando nessa condição:

```
($(this).val() == '3' || '4')
```

ela deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
($(this).val() == '3' || $(this).val() == '4')
```

Segue a correção de seu fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7t9u4yeq/

Observações sobre o seu fiddle:

**1º erro**

A linha `var tip = document.getElementById("#id2").val;` está errada, pois para se recuperar o valor de um select list usando javascript deve-se retornar o valor da opção selecionada, então no caso ficaria:

```
var tip = document.getElementById("id2").options[e.selectedIndex].value
```

ou usando-se jquery

```
var tip = $("#id2").val();
```

**2º erro**

As condições como já falado nessa reposta

**3º erro**

O evento deve ser capturado quando qualquer um dos dois dropdowns for modificado, entao deve ser adicionado mais um seletor ao evento

```
$('#id1, #id2').change(function(){}
```

Como agora o evento pode ser chamado em qualquer um dos dropdowns devemos mudar na condição aonde usamos `$(this).val()`, para `$('id1').val()`

Comment: Muito bom, valeu mesmo, esclareceu muita coisa... Abraço!